# Fatal exception: AsyncTask #1?

Tags: java, android, sql

I am trying to connect my Android device to MySQL DB which is running on MySQL Server. But I keep getting the error stated below.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction here?

**LOGCAT**

```
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/TdsCore
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:359)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at com.example.rf.MainActivity.runSQL(MainActivity.java:110)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at com.example.rf.MainActivity$DoInBackground.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:58)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at com.example.rf.MainActivity$DoInBackground.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-15 09:17:21.708: E/AndroidRuntime(19677):    ... 4 more
```

**CODE**

How I call it:

```
new DoInBackground().execute();
```

The methods:

```
private class DoInBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>   
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...unused) {
        String response = "";
        try {
            runSQL();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.i("Error", e.toString());           
        }
        return null;   
    }
}

public void runSQL()
{
    String connectionString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server:1433/DBNAME;instance=SQLEXPRESS";
    String userName = "username";
    String password = "password";
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"); //specify the jtds driver

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, userName, password); //establish connection
        //System.out.println("Connection properly established");
        Log.i("Success", "Connected to DB");
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"SD Card failed":e.getMessage();
        Log.e("sdcard-err2:",err);  
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have found the problem. The problem was, I was using ktds 1.3.1 as the driver to connect to the DB, but this version is bugged. So switching back to 1.3.0 version solved my problems.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/TdsCore....there is some authentication you fail to provide.

Comment: Right ok, so by this you mean I have failed to provide say a username for example?

Comment: may be a username and password.

Comment: @user3836282: Where is the SQL DB supposed to reside? Is it in the android client or a server?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to connect your server's SQL from android client.
You cannot directly connect to SQL server from android client. 
You need to create web-services at your server end for it.

- If server is JAVA then you can use [REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html).
- On the Android side you can use [this simple RestClient](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/) to work with that REST service.
- For JSON <--> Object mapping on both sides (Android, Java back-end) you can use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Inside the web-service, you can use appropriate JDBC Connections..